# why scanf isn't taking input?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I am making a simple calculator using if else statement, but my 2nd scanf where the user is giving the input as choosing the operator, it is not taking the input there.

```
// making a calculator
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    int ans;
    char c;

    printf("Enter your first number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the operator '+','-','*','/': \n");
    scanf("%c", &c); //isn't taking the input here
    printf("Enter your second number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if (c == '+')
    {
        ans = a+b;
        printf("Your answer is: %d",ans);
    }
    else if (c == '-')
    {
        ans = a-b;
        printf("Your answer is: %d", ans);
    }
    else if (c == '*')
    {
        ans = a*b;
        printf("Your answer is: %d", ans);
    }
    else if (c == '/')
    {
        ans = a/b;
        printf("Your answer is: %d", ans);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

all is okay but the the input where the user will put the operator isn't taking the input.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &c);` -> `scanf(" %c", &c);` i.e. add a space before `%c`.

Comment: Don't use `scanf( )` much, but you could try `scanf( "%d%c%d", &a, &c, &b );` and see how you go... (That is, get all three pieces in a single operation...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Likely better as `"%d %c%d"`. (Add space)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Closed before I could post trivial prototype... Put it into a loop so I used `" %d %c %d"`to also toss away the '\n' for the subsequent rounds... Worked when input was "45+50" and " 45 + 50"... Nice... :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Note the spaces before `"%d"` are not necessary, yet cause no harm either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
printf("Enter your first number: \n"); scanf("%d", &a); 
printf("Enter the operator '+','-','*','/': \n");
scanf("%c", &c); 
printf("Enter your second number: \n"); 
scanf("%d", &b);
```

When you are done entering input into the first `scanf()` call, the input has a `\n` at the end. `scanf()` only reads characters that match the format specifier (`%d` in your first call), characters that do not match the format specific cause `scanf()` to stop scanning and will cause it to leave invalid characters in the `stdin` buffer.

In your case when you enter a `int` it is ended with a `\n` (newline character). This does not match the `%d` format specifier and is left in the `stdin` buffer. This will then cause the next `scanf()` call to read the newline character and look like it has just skipped a call.

Solution:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Note:

`scanf()` is a quick and dirty input function, you should consider learning how to use something more reliable such as `fgets()`.